# Is possible pass parameter to a property?

Tags: c#, wpf

if I've this property:

```
public ListView GetCurrentListView
```

can I pass parameter such as

```
public ListView GetCurrentListView(bool flag)
```

?

Comment: A property with a parameter is called an "indexer" in C# parlance.  However, based on the WPF tag I suspect you might really be asking about dependency properties, which are not properties at all.  If that's the case, please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: Isn't a property with a parameter called "method"? 

Comment: The active verb "Get" hints that this is likely a _method_ rather than a _property_.

Answer (score 1):

Your second example is no longer a property, but rather a method.

You can not have a method and property of the same name.  You should generally do one or the other, but if you need both a property and a method, you will need to use different names for each.

Answer (score 1):

Only option is indexer property and you can specify the type of a property as a delegate:

```
void Main()
{
    var sample = new Sample();
    var odd = sample.Numbers(true);
}
class Sample
{
    public Func<bool, IEnumerable<int>> Numbers 
    { 
        get => b => Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => b ? x * 2 : x * 2 - 1); 
    }
}
```